# ad server solution

Tags: ads, openx

i am looking for an open source ad server that serves advertising from my sales team and if there aren`t any to show from an advertising network set by me

i want to add different websites and the advertiser can select on which zone and site to publish the banners

i tried to use openx, but my first experience was that it is really slow:(

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Cosmin,

I'm using OpenX and I managed to obtain more than several hundreds ads delivered per seconds. What do you mean is it slow, did you performed some benchmarks?

Comment: interesting...i tested openx(the free version) on an virtual machine, probably i did something wrong:|
for now i installed some commercial script and for now does what i need:)

Comment: ok. if you plan to test openx in future I can point you to the proper documentation (using jmeter)